# Iterator and iteratorList with synchronization in java

Tags: java

i  have an arraylist and i want to add and remove many items at he same(almost) time. So i decide to create 2 methods. In the first method i implement the method which contains the remove part i use something like:

```
   //my list
   ArrayList<Human> list= new ArrayList<Human>(100);

   //Human is the object of the class Human
   List<Human> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Human>());
   synchronized (syncList){

    for (Iterator<Human> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
       Human = iter.next();
              -
              -
          //using the removes method of the iterator
          it.removes(something);
```

And in the second method (which i need to add many items) something like this:

```
            for(  ListIterator<Human> it = list.listIterator();it.hasNext();){  
            List<Human> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(newArrayList<Human>());
        synchronized (syncList){
                   -
                   - 
          //using the add method of the iterator list
          it.add(something)
```

Now i realize that when those two void methods finished and the list called by another function don't have the appropriate behaviour. I mean that some of the elements didn't add or removed from the list. How can i fix this?any ideas?

Comment: add and remove directly from the list?

Comment: The two methods use their own, local list. They don't share the same list.

Comment: the list is global. i just added there in order to see and the list i actually use.sorry for the confuse

Comment: yes, add and remove directly from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are synchronizing on 2 entirely different objects, hence the inconsistent behavior.  your call to `synchronizedList()` is returning a *wrapper* around the original list, on which you are synchronizing.  since the 2 methods are using different wrappers, no actual synchronization is happening.  you just need to synchronize on the original list implementation.  of course, any *other* usage of the list member should *also* be synchronized.